# Converting string items to indicators

Tags: r

The input is:

```
data.frame(rbind(c("3,2,98"),c("5,3,1")))
```

And the wanted output table is

```
    3  2  98  5  1
1.  1  1   1  0  0
2.  1  0   0  1  1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data really are like what you show in your question (strings), I would suggest `concat.split.expanded` from my "splitstackshape" package (development version).

Here's how you get the package:

```
library(devtools)
install_github(repo = "splitstackshape", username = "mrdwab", ref = "devel")
library(splitstackshape)
```

Here's your data. I've added a nicer variable name than what you had shared in your question.

```
X <- data.frame(V1 = rbind(c("3,2,98"),c("5,3,1")))
```

Here's the splitting step. Add `drop = TRUE` if you don't want to retain the original column.

```
concat.split.expanded(X, split.col = "V1", sep = ",", 
                      type = "character", fill = 0)
#       V1 V1_1 V1_2 V1_3 V1_5 V1_98
# 1 3,2,98    0    1    1    0     1
# 2  5,3,1    1    0    1    1     0
```

---

If your data are more like the following:

```
X2 <- data.frame(matrix(c(3, 2, 98, 5, 3, 1), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
X2
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  3  2 98
# 2  5  3  1
```

... then a `table` approach (in combination with `stack`) can be used:

```
table(cbind(rn = sequence(nrow(X2)), stack(X2))[c("rn", "values")])
#    values
# rn  1 2 3 5 98
#   1 0 1 1 0  1
#   2 1 0 1 1  0
```